# Req.user lost between POST and GET

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am new to Node and starting with the [Rocket Rides demo](http://github.com/stripe/stripe-connect-rocketrides). The pilot sign-up works on the web app and I want to do the same for passengers on the web (whereas the demo has passenger signup on iOS). I can't understand why the `req.user` is maintained with the original code for pilots and not my adaptation for passengers.

I added `console.log()` in the GET of `server/routes/pilots/pilots.js`:

```js
/**
 * GET /pilots/signup
 *
 * Display the signup form on the right step depending on the current completion.
 */
router.get('/signup', (req, res) => {
  let step = 'account';
  console.log("*** Req.user = " + req.user);
  // ...
});
```

and in the POST:

```js
/**
 * POST /pilots/signup
 *
 * Create a user and update profile information during the pilot onboarding process.
 */
router.post('/signup', async (req, res, next) => {
  const body = Object.assign({}, req.body, {
    // Use `type` instead of `pilot-type` for saving to the DB.
    type: req.body['pilot-type'],
    'pilot-type': undefined,
  });

  // Check if we have a logged-in pilot
  let pilot = req.user;
  if (!pilot) {
    try {
      // Try to create and save a new pilot
      pilot = new Pilot(body);
      pilot = await pilot.save()
      // Sign in and redirect to continue the signup process
      req.logIn(pilot, err => {
        if (err) next(err);
        console.log("About to redirect with:");
        console.log(pilot);
        return res.redirect('/pilots/signup');
      });
    } catch (err) {
      // Show an error message to the user
      const errors = Object.keys(err.errors).map(field => err.errors[field].message);
      res.render('pilot-signup', { step: 'account', error: errors[0] });
    }
  } 
  else {
    // ...
  }
});
```

The code for passengers is similar and I include it at the bottom. The server logs for pilot sign-up show:

```
*** Req.user = undefined
GET /pilots/signup 200 136.726 ms - 1865
GET /stylesheets/rocketrides.css 304 0.911 ms - -
GET /javascripts/rocketrides.js 304 1.043 ms - -
GET /images/header.jpg 304 5.187 ms - -
GET /images/rocketrides.svg 304 10.075 ms - -
About to redirect with:
{
  rocket: { country: 'US' },
  type: 'individual',
  country: 'US',
  _id: 5e7e24d38794fa32032fd052,
  email: 'name@example.com',
  password: '...',
  created: 2020-03-27T16:07:47.054Z,
  __v: 0
}
POST /pilots/signup 302 116.113 ms - 72
*** Req.user = {
  rocket: { country: 'US' },
  type: 'individual',
  country: 'US',
  _id: 5e7e24d38794fa32032fd052,
  email: 'name@example.com',
  password: '...',
  created: 2020-03-27T16:07:47.054Z,
  __v: 0
}
GET /pilots/signup 200 93.455 ms - 6018
```

The logs for the passenger sign-up, which I customized, show:

```
*** Req.user = undefined
GET /passengers/signup 200 165.900 ms - 1869
GET /stylesheets/rocketrides.css 304 2.573 ms - -
GET /javascripts/rocketrides.js 304 1.161 ms - -
GET /images/header.jpg 304 4.349 ms - -
GET /images/rocketrides.svg 304 4.423 ms - -
About to redirect with:
{
  rocket: { country: 'US' },
  type: 'individual',
  _id: 5e7e259d8794fa32032fd053,
  email: 'name@example.com',
  password: '...',
  created: 2020-03-27T16:11:09.273Z,
  __v: 0
}
POST /passengers/signup 302 32.873 ms - 80
*** Req.user = undefined
GET /passengers/signup 200 137.442 ms - 1869
```

In both cases `req.user` starts with `undefined`, then the user (passenger or pilot) is saved to the database, and the code redirects to GET with a valid object. With pilots, that object is received by the GET request, but not for passengers.

The app already uses state session in `app.js` and works for one type of sign-up, so my question is different from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16434893/node-express-passport-req-user-undefined). It might be something obvious to most and buried in the code for a  newbie. I also included the `passport.serializeUser()` from `pilots.js` into `passengers.js`.

How can I fix the problem, or debug it?

### extras

The code for the GET of `server/routes/passengers/passengers.js`:

```js
/**
 * GET /passengers/signup
 *
 * Display the signup form on the right step depending on the current completion.
 */
router.get('/signup', (req, res) => {
  let step = 'account';
  console.log("*** Req.user = " + req.user);
  // ...
});
```

The code for the POST in the same file:

```js
/**
 * POST /passengers/signup
 *
 * Create a user and update profile information during the passenger onboarding process.
 */
router.post('/signup', async (req, res, next) => {
  const body = Object.assign({}, req.body, {
    // Use `type` instead of `passenger-type` for saving to the DB.
    type: req.body['passenger-type'],
    'passenger-type': undefined,
  });

  // Check if we have a logged-in passenger
  let passenger = req.user;
  if (!passenger) {
    try {
      // Try to create and save a new passenger
      passenger = new Passenger(body);
      passenger = await passenger.save()

      // Sign in and redirect to continue the signup process
      req.logIn(passenger, err => {
        if (err) next(err);
        console.log("About to redirect with:");
        console.log(passenger);
        return res.redirect('/passengers/signup');
      });
    } catch (err) {
      // Show an error message to the user
      const errors = Object.keys(err.errors).map(field => err.errors[field].message);
      res.render('passenger-signup', { step: 'account', error: errors[0] });
    }
  } 
  else {
    // ...
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not understand the Passport strategy, and the passenger user was being serialized and deserialized as a pilot. Only the first `passport.serialize()` function is valid; when I imported `passengers.js` first, pilots were being serialized and deserialized as passengers.

See [this post](http://toon.io/understanding-passportjs-authentication-flow/) for how passport works (pointed from [PassportJS serializeUser and deserializeUser execution flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29066348/passportjs-serializeuser-and-deserializeuser-execution-flow)), and [this Github issue](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/issues/50) for how to handle multiple local strategies with a single serialization and deserialization.

In my case, I will use a `user` class that passengers and pilots inherit from.